# Stylelint won't recognize type import

Tags: typescript, stylelint

I've begun working in a large repo where no types are being exported or imported anywhere. This seemed odd until I attempted to do so and realized why: we're using stylelint (13.4.0) and it simply won't recognize `import type { WhateverType }`. It produces an "Unexpected token" response.

Not even disabling the next line works:

```
/* stylelint-disable-next-line */
import type { ThingProps } from '@/components/Thing/';
```

This is in a file that doesn't even have any style declarations (we use styled components, btw), but I would not want to preclude them by having stylelint ignore the whole file.

We have a commit hook running stylelint, so no commits can go in with imported styles, and that sucks. I'd like to figure out how to work around this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the `>= 1.10.0` of https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-processor-styled-components or whatever your equivalent processor is for updated TS syntax support. See [this PR](https://github.com/styled-components/stylelint-processor-styled-components/pull/296) as an example.